# How does Neo know the question "What's the matrix?" in the first place?

Tags: the-matrix, continuity

In the beginning of the movie, Neo follows the "white rabbit" to a club. There Trinity tells him that he already knows "the question".

He does, it is "What's the matrix?" and this is indeed what he answers.

But how does he know this question already? Did somebody tell him? Was it a rumour on the web?

Comment: "The Matrix has you"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Neo know it was Morpheus on the phone and what The Matrix is?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60769/how-did-neo-know-it-was-morpheus-on-the-phone-and-what-the-matrix-is)

Comment: Welcome to SFF!  See [this very similar question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60769/how-did-neo-know-it-was-morpheus-on-the-phone-and-what-the-matrix-is?rq=1)

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - It's similar, but I don't think the answers there particularly focus on whether (and how) Neo has heard of the Matrix before he meets Morpheus.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet They are not duplicate.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - I've marked the other one for closure as lacking focus since it asks two distinct questions, one about Morpheus (not a dupe and well answered) and one about Neo's knowledge of the Matrix (fairly dupey but poorly answered). It would be better if we had a focused question one each.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of the theatrical movie, it's not really apparent what Neo does (or doesn't) know about The Matrix at the start of the film. Certainly he's been trying to get into contact with Morpheus, a known cyber-criminal, for reasons that aren't really clear and he seems to have some idea that the world isn't right, but can't find any way to vocalise it. He has what Morpheus refers to as a 'splinter in his mind'.

Trinity tells him that...

> *The Matrix has you...*

...shortly before Choi and DuJour turn up at his apartment and take him to the nightclub, so we know he's heard about the Matrix at least once before his conversation with her.

---

In earlier versions of the script, Neo is watching other hackers discussing rumours about something called the Matrix. None of them have a clue what it is, but they do know it's something shady.

> We are on-line, inside a chat room called "The Matrix."
> It is an exklusive web-site where hackers hang out.
>
> [SCREEN]
> JACKON: I heard Morpheus has been
> on this board.
> SUPERASTIC: Morpheus doesn't even
> exist and the Matrix is nothing
> but an advertising gimmick 4 a new
> game.
> TIMAXE: All I want to know is
> Trinity really a girl?
> LODIII: 87% of all women on line
> are really men.
> QUARK: The Matrix is a euphemism
> for the government.
> SUPERASTIC: No, The Matrix is the
> system controlling our lives.
> TIMAXE:  You mean MTV.
> SUPERASTIC:  I mean Sega.
> FOS4:  ALL HAIL SEGA!!!

Comment: "The Matrix has you..."   that indeed explains it, thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this chat exchange is realistic.

Comment: "gimmick 4 a new game" I guess the hackers are so 7331 that it shows up even in their speech.